# How to define combined shortcuts followed by the grave accent ` (backtik) in Emacs auctex?

Tags: emacs, auctex, shortcut

I know how to define a new shortcut for grave accent followed by a single key.

For example the below code assign the shortcut `` `8 `` for inserting `\times` in a latex document.

`(add-to-list 'LaTeX-math-list '(?8 "times" nil))`

How to do the same thing for a combined shortcut, for example, I would like to assign the shortcut `` ` `` `M-p` (that is, `` ` `` followed by the Meta key, followed by p ) for `\perp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining key sequences is one the darker corners of Emacs.  Try something like this in your init file:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-math-list '(("M-p" "perp" nil nil)))
```

Note that the value of `LaTeX-math-list` must be set before you start the math  mode, otherwise it is not seen by the function `LaTeX-math-initialize` which sets everything up.

You can also use the custom interface if you want it the easy way.  That would look like this:

> [image]